# Dynamic Docker base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that needs to get base image tag from the command line and load it dynamically, but I am getting this error with this command line.

```
$ docker build --network=host --build-arg sample_TAG=7.0  --rm=true .

Step 9/12 : FROM "${sample_TAG}"
base name ("${sample_TAG}") should not be blank
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 as maven-build

ARG sample_TAG

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8


WORKDIR /apps/sample-google


COPY . /apps/sample-google


RUN mvn clean package



RUN echo "image tag is ${sample_TAG}"

FROM $sample_TAG


VOLUME /apps

RUN mkdir /apps/sample-google
COPY --from=maven-build  /apps/sample-google/target /apps/sample-google
```

The echo line prints 'latest' string correctly, but it fails in 'FROM $sample_TAG' line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that, you need to define Global ARGs and better to have some default value and override it during build time.

```
ARG sample_TAG=test
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 as maven-build
ARG sample_TAG
WORKDIR /apps/sample-google
RUN echo "image tag is ${sample_TAG}"
FROM $sample_TAG
VOLUME /apps
RUN mkdir /apps/sample-google
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
ARG sample_TAG
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 as maven-build
...
FROM $sample_TAG
```