# Can I reference an environment variable in a Dockerfile FROM statement?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-registry-mirror

What I'd like to do is this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-alpine
# more stuff
```

But, this needs to run on an isolated clean build machine which does not have internet access, so I need to route it through a local mirror server (e.g. Artifactory or Nexus or another similar thing)

If the docker image were hosted on docker hub (e.g. FROM ubuntu) then the `--registry-mirrors docker` configuration option would solve it for us.
BUT because microsoft have decided not to use docker hub, the registry mirror thing isn't working either.

After much effort, I've set up a a custom domain mirror for mcr.microsoft.com and so now I can do this:

```
FROM microsoft-docker-mirror.local.domain/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-alpine
# more stuff
```

That works. But we have remote workers who may not be on the local office LAN and can't see my local mirror server. What I now want to do is vary it depending on environment. E.g.

```
ENV MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO mcr.microsoft.com
FROM ${MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO}/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-alpine
```

My isolated build machine would set the `MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO` environment variable, and everyone else's machines would use the default `mcr.microsoft.com`

Anyway. Adding the `ENV` line to the dockerfile results in docker throwing this error:

```
Error response from daemon: No build stage in current context
```

There seem to be lots of references to the fact that the FROM line **must** be the first line in the file, before even any comments... 
How can I reference an environment variable in my FROM statement? Or alternatively, how can I make registry mirrors work for things that aren't docker hub?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use ARG instead of ENV. Here is some workaround https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9844

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913617/dynamic-docker-base-image/57916700#57916700

Comment: The images aren't available on Docker Hub but are still `docker` images, e.g. you can configure `nexus` as a `docker` proxy to `mcr.microsoft.com` then configure your `docker` daemon to use `nexus` as your `--registry-mirrors` - e.g. use `nexus` as a pull through cache similar to using a normal [registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"`ARG` is the only instruction that may precede `FROM` in the `Dockerfile`" - [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from).

```
ARG MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO=mcr.microsoft.com
FROM ${MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO}/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-alpine
```

Build with a non-default `MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO` using the `--build-arg`: `docker build --rm --build-arg MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO=repo.example.com -t so:58196638 .`

**Note**: you can pass the `--build-arg` from the hosts environment i.e. `MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO=repo.example.com docker build --rm --build-arg MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO=${MICROSOFT_DOCKER_REPO} -t so:58196638 .`

Comment: @OrionEdwards - glad I could help and thanks for the edit.